# Is it valid to combine friending and templating in this code?

Tags: c++, c++14

This code compiles in GCC, clang etc

```
template <int a, typename T>
class A{
        private:
                int B=1;

        friend A<-a, T> func(A a_in){
                A<-a, T> val;
                val.B = 10;
                return val;
        }
};

int main(){
  A<1, int> mya;
  auto bb= func(mya);
}
```

but I am trying to make func a templated function like this:

```
template <int a, typename T>
class A{
        template<int, typename> friend class A;
        private:
                int B=1;

        public:
template<typename num>
        friend A<-a, T> func(A a_in, num num_in){
                A<-a, T> val;
                val.B = 10;
                return val;
        }
};

int main(){
A<1, int> mya;
auto bbb= func(mya, 1);
}
```

That works in clang with or without explicitly friending other As, and works in g++ of 13 or newer as long as that is done.
Older g++ complains about privacy of the B member in this case

```
error: ‘int A<-1, int>::B’ is private within this context
   14 |                 val.B = 10;
```

Oddly, it also gives an error of "error: ‘func’ was not declared in this scope" if I try and specialise explicitly in the call (i.e. `auto bb= func<int>(mya, 1);`) *unless* I also specify std=c++20 which suggests the code could be doing something ill defined.

Questions:

1. Should this work, or is func some sort of partial specialisation which should not be friend-able like that?
2. Why does clang permit access to the private members of A even for different template params, and why does gcc allow it too for the single-argument version of func? I thought that each specialisation was effectively a different class.
3. Is there any other way I can access private members of other specialisations of A?

Comment: *"This code compiles in GCC, clang etc..."* No it [does not](https://godbolt.org/z/KoP3rrTW7).

Comment: Remove the `-` from `A<-a, T>` and it will [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/j75G7xfs8)

Comment: It does? https://godbolt.org/z/43E7x8G5c

Comment: You need both `A<-a,T>` and `<a,T>` friends. Function's code requires both because of `val.B` access

Comment: @Heather Your second snippet also [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/M97sWK1vz) with gcc lower than 13 but in your question you say that it doesn't compile with gcc 13 lower.

Comment: You need to actually call func to see the error there, I just didn't include that part as it's trivial. Edited it in now

Comment: @Heather You should ask **one question per post**. Just have one snippet imo in your question(and remove the other) so that it would not be confusing what you're asking. You can ask about the other in a new separate question.

Comment: Before c++23 `this`-deduction the only easy way is incapsulation. if you absolutely need a restricted API access, then a CRTP with "accessor" (also easier with c++23)

Comment: Also I have seen gcc bugs where they allow access to private members(when they shouldn't) and also bugs that sometimes don't allow access when they should've. So it's confusing which of the bugs apply here(if any).